# Swift Bridging Header import issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, bridging-header, objective-c-swift-bridge

Following instructions, I've created a bridging header and added to my project. Unfortunately, the following error occurred:

> :0: error: could not import Objective-C header '---path--to---header/....h'

[image: Screenshot 1]

In build settings I added header search path string to the location of bridging header, but nothing helped.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: You could rather than add the header file yourself. Use the New File.. to add a new blank Objective-c .m file.  This will make xcode offer you a header-bridge file where you can add your imports. You can then delete the .m file you just added

Comment: Yep, i've tried this way certainly too, but nothing helped

Comment: Is this on a fresh project or the same one you did by hand?

Comment: It's on fresh project, i've aded Keychain support wrapper, that i once wrote on OBJC

Comment: Sorry. Not sure what you mean by the added Keychain support wrapper. But I notice you are on iOS do you get the same thing with an  OSX project which is what I have been using

Comment: Didn't try OS X honestly, has anyone already successfully ported Obj-C code in swift via bridging header technique?

Comment: I'm sure there must be or we world have heard more about it. I have partially done it in answering another question I used it to import a iTunes.h file for scripting bridge. But I have not fully tested it.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Be careful to add the file to the folder that your error is complaining!
I've made the same mistake, if you create the file from Xcode, it will go to the folder: Project->Project->Header.h

And Xcode is looking for Project->Header.h

That means you need to put the file inside your project folder (ProjectName->ProjectNameFolder)!

UPDATED:
I'm not sure if I got what you mean, but try this to solve your problem:

1. Delete all your bridging files that you created until now.
2. Select the main folder of project and hit new file->iOS->Header file.
3. Write your imports in the header file created.
4. Select the project inside Xcode->Build Settings, type in search field: bridging and put in the key SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER the name of your header file or the path to it!

If you follow this steps, your header file will be created at the correct location!

Comment: Well, i just tried this method, the header is really visible, but, unfortunately, bridging Obj-C classes are still invisible ( after including them in bridging header )

Comment: At first the answer says "Need to put the file at the same level of xcodeproj", at the end, it says "ensure the file is ...not in the same level of xcodeproj".  Why?

Comment: I meant that the file must be located inside de subfolder of project, not at the same level as xcodeproj. Example: In the folder of your project you have project, project.xcodeproj and projecttests. The file must be inside project folder :)

Comment: guys for me I had to ./PATHTOBRIDGINGHEADER/BRIDGINGHEADER

Comment: I tried everything but nothnig works for me. This is very irritating. I am working with xcode 8 and swift 3. Can you help me

Comment: I'm confused you say "That means you need to put the file at the same level of xcodeproj!" but after you said "Ensure that the file is located inside the main folder of the project not in the same level of xcodeproj!" which one is it?

Comment: @bakalolo, you're correct, I've edited the answer. You should put it inside your project folder. The important thing is to keep the build settings (Objective-C Bridging Header section) with the same path as your bridge file!

Comment: AWESOME! WORKS LIKE A CHARM! :D

Comment: the mangled English here makes it completely impossible to figure out what's going on. I wish an editor would clean this up.

Comment: doesn't mean a thing in xcode 9:
SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER

Answer (score 68):

In my case this was actually an error as a result of a circular reference. I had a class imported in the bridging header, and that class' header file was importing the swift header (`<MODULE_NAME>-Swift.h`). I was doing this because in the Obj-C header file I needed to use a class that was declared in Swift, the solution was to simply use the `@class` declarative.

So basically the error said "Failed to import bridging header", the error above it said `<MODULE_NAME>-Swift.h` file not found, above that was an error pointing at a specific Obj-C Header file (namely a View Controller).

Inspecting this file I noticed that it had the -Swift.h declared inside the header. Moving this import to the implementation resolved the issue. So I needed to use an object, lets call it `MyObject` defined in Swift, so I simply changed the header to say

```
@class MyObject;
```

Comment: This is silly but moving it to implementation file worked for me too. Unfortunately I needed it in the header because my class implements a delegate defined in a swift file. But since obj-c doesn't care if my class actually implements the delegate when I pass it in, I'll settle with this. But ideally there'd be another way

Comment: You may also have to check the imports of the one you're bringing into the bridging header. If any of those imported classes have a reference to the "-Swift.h" file you'll have to move the declaration to the .m.

Answer (score 30):

Find the path at:

**Build Settings／Swift Compiler－Code Generation／Objective-C Bridging Header**

and delete that file. Then you should be ok.

Comment: You win. I wasted so much time on this. Simple and effective. Xcode is doing something screwy with this path, like appending it to $(SRCROOT) behind the scenes. I think having a space in my path could be part of the problem but this was the silver bullet.

Comment: how do you delete that file?

Comment: In Xcode 8 - instead of "Code Generation" it is in Swift Compiler－General.

Comment: Thanks you save me...
Thanks a lot

Comment: After deleting this I'm getting this error "Cannot find 'GeneratedPluginRegistrant' in scope"

Answer (score 18):

This will probably only affect a small percentage of people, but in my case my project was using CocoaPods and one of those pods had a sub spec with its own CocoaPods. The solution was to use full angle imports to reference any files in the sub-pods.

```
#import <HexColors/HexColor.h>
```

Rather than

```
#import "HexColor.h"
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: This was the problem for me. I got "Failed to import Bridging header" and the "Could not find XYZ.h" errors. Making this change solved it for me on Xcode 6.4 and Swift 1.2.

Comment: @danielgomezrico One statement points to the file in a subdirectory. The other points to a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: The solution for this error for me when using CocoaPods was simply running pod install again after creating the new configuration.

Answer (score 16):

For me deleting the **derived data** fixed it , I noticed even if I check out from an old commit, the same issue happens.

You can reach that option form Window-> Projects .

Answer (score 10):

"we need to tell **Xcode** where to look for the **header files** we’re listing in our **bridging header**. Find the Search Paths section, and change the project-level setting for **User Header Search Paths**, adding a recursive entry for the ‘Pods’ directory: **Pods/**** "
http://swiftalicio.us/2014/11/using-cocoapods-from-swift/

Answer (score 9):

For me it was because I forgot to add it to the Target's Build Settings.

[image]

Comment: This may help if you have only added it to the project's build settings.

Answer (score 6):

I've also experienced this problem and sadly it is just a bug in the SDK + Xcode. I talked to an engineer at WWDC, about this and a few other problems I was having with CloudKit. These bugs will be addressed in the next seed of Xcode.

It's the fun part about using beta software.

Comment: Yeah, it's frustrating. My team and I was working trying to figure out an NSURL problem with CloudKit and we couldn't figure out why we were getting errors, turns out it was a server side problem by apple. we couldn't even do anything. wasted so much time. haha.

Comment: The issue can actually be resolved by placing the header in the correct location. What worked for me is calling the header Project-Bridging-Header.h and placing it in the root of my project folder tree (as a sibling of my main Xcode project file). See @renan-kosicki answer

Comment: Fixed in an Xcode update, this was caused because of an issue with the early betas.

Answer (score 3):

for others who have troubles to add swift class into objective-c project.
this is what work for me :

1. create NEW swift file. this will make xcode to prompt if you want xcode to create all settings for mix swift-objective-c project including brigde-header.h for you. press yes.
2. now, add your existing swift files you want to use in your project.
3. in the implementation file you are going to use the swift class add :
   #import "YOURPROJECTNAME-swift.h" . this file xcode create for you.
   if your xcode project is myProject then "myProject-swift.h"

and that's it. now create the swift class in your code like it was objective-c.

Answer (score 3):

I imported in some files from bridgin header files from cocoapods not in a proper way.

Instead of importing

```
#import <SomeCocoaPod/SomeCocoaPod.h>
```

I wrote

```
#import "SomeCocoaPod.h"
```

And this was my HUGE mistake

Answer (score 2):

Add a temporary Objective-C file to your project. You may give it any name you like.

Select Yes to configure an Objective-C bridging header.

Delete the temporary Objective-C file you just created.

In the projectName-Bridging-Header.h file just created, add this line:

*'#import < GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h >'*

**Edit the AppDelegate.swift file:**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIza....") //iOS API key

    return true
}
```

[Follow the link](http://studyswift.blogspot.com/2015/10/using-google-maps-api-in-swift.html) for full sample

Answer (score 2):

For me it was not selecting 'Copy items if needed' in destination path while adding the framework. Simply re-add the framework with this option selected.

Answer (score 1):

After initial few days of struggle, I finally managed to successfully integrate Facebook signup to my iOS app. Here are the steps(I am assuming you have already installed Facebook SDK v4.1 or above in your machines):

1. Add the Facebook frameworks - FBSDKCoreKit,FBSDKLoginKit under your project.
2. Make no changes in the Build settings as FB SDK v4.1 and above doesn't need anymore bridging header files.
3. Import the FBSDKCorekit, FBSDKLoginKit in ViewController.swift, AppDelegate.swift files
4. Add informations in the pList as mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started)
5. Build your app. And wohoo! no compile time errors.

Comment: This answer would be better if you included details from the linked page. If the linked page changes or the link ceases to work, people reading this answer will not know what to do when they come across step 4.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue for different reason , **here is my case** I build project that needs slide menu to be included , I am using SWRevealViewController lib to approach that

when I import the library files I add sub-folder(SWRevealViewController) under Supporting Files for .h && .m files , it fire two errors , cant import bridge and SWRevealViewController.h is not found .

**How I fix it**

when I move files to Supporting Files directly (delete sub-folder) , SWRevealViewController.m automatically added to Build Phases --> Compile Sources and issue is gone

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue that could not be solved by any solution above. My project uses CocoaPods. I noticed that along with errors I got a warning with the following message:

```
Uncategorized: Target 'Pods' of project 'Pods' was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'Pods.framework' because its architectures 'arm64' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 arm64'
```

[image]

So solution was quite simple. For Pods project, change *Build Active Architecture Only* flag to **No** and original error went away.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced that kind of error, when I was adding a Today Extension to my app. The build target for the extension was generated with the same name of bridging header as my app's build target. This was leading to the error, because the extension does not see the files listed in the bridging header of my app.

The only thing You need to to is delete or change the name of the bridging header for the extension and all will be fine.

Hope that this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I actually created an empty OSX Source Objective C file under the project (where all my swift files are).

I added the imports and then deleted the **.m** file.

Answer (score 0):

Amongst the other fixes, I had the error come up when I tried to do Product->Archive. Turns out I had this :

```
Objective-C Bridging Header
  Debug (had the value)
  Release (had the value)
    Any architecture | Any SDK (this was blank - problem here!)
```

After setting it in that last line, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Set **Precompile Bridging Header** to **No** fix the problem for me.

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a legit solution for some people. I've benchmarked doing iterative builds with this on and off on a large project and see no difference at all (Apple has seen up to 30% speedups), but the amount of time I lose clearing build files and building from scratch is substantial