# Add FacebookSDK to test target Xcode 6

Tags: unit-testing, swift, xcode6, facebook-sdk-3.1

I'm trying to test a FacebookAPI class I created, but when I add it to the test target, all my FacebookSDK classes inside FacebookAPI get "Use of unresolved identifier 'FBSession'" for example.

What should I do?

I'm using swift, thats why I have to add the FacebookAPI to the test target.

Comment: You need a bridging header. You can take a look SO posts like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146677/swift-bridging-header-import-issue  Better yet you should read the apple book 'Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C'

Comment: I already have a bridging header, thats how my FacebookAPI class can see the FacebookSDK if it is not in the test target.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that you need to make sure that you have included the FBSDK Framework in the *Link Binary With Libraries* settings under *Build Phases* for your test target!

I used cocoapods and forgot to add the pods for my test target! Silly me.

Here's what my podfile looks like:

`target 'AppName' do
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
end
target 'AppTests' do
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
end`