# Using Google Analytics with Swift on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I'm trying to use GA with a Swift project.

I installed the SDK correctly but I can't send Screen Measurements manually because some objects are not found.

Here's the code given by Google:

```
// May return nil if a tracker has not already been initialized with a
// property ID.
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

// This screen name value will remain set on the tracker and sent with
// hits until it is set to a new value or to nil.
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName
   value:@"Home Screen"];

// New SDK versions
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];
```

Here's my code:

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance()
tracker.setValue(kGai, forKey: "/index")
tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build)
```

And here's the errors I get:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'kGAIScreenName'
Use of unresolved identifier 'GAIDictionaryBuilder'
```

I imported GAI.h in my BridingHeader and added frameworks to the build file, no errors on this side.

Thanks!

Comment: r u integrated the GAIDictionaryBuilder.h in your header file and GAI file

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the `defaultTracker` part in the first line. Also, did you set up the bridging header?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

OK so I just added GAI.h to my bridging header but didn't add others header files.
And thanks DPLusV I also didn't translated correctly Obj-C to Swift.

Here is my final code which works:

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "/index")
tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build())
```

**[EDIT] SWIFT 3**

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
tracker?.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "/index")
let build = (GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as NSDictionary) as! [AnyHashable: Any]
tracker?.send(build)
```

Comment: thanks, this worked for me. wish google added some documentation for swift - since I don't know ObjC all I can do is guess how to transform it to swift syntax...

Comment: Make sure you `#import "GAIFields.h"` in order to use `kGAIScreenName`

Comment: @I use Xcode 6.3beta with Swift 1.2 and get the following error: Cannot invoke 'send' with an argument list of type '(NSMutableDictionary!)'

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591930/google-analytics-not-working-with-swift-1-2-and-xcode-6-3

Comment: @JonathanEllis also "#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"

Comment: create Bridging header file 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146677/swift-bridging-header-import-issue/26729748

Answer (score 5):

I followed the instructions in

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift

up till pod installation

I already had a GoogleService-Info.plist file there I enabled the google analytics

Then I did some hit and trial methods to make it work

And finally I found some thing which worked for me

```
let googleAnalytics : GAITracker = GAI.sharedInstance().trackerWithTrackingId("UA-XXXXXXXX-X")
GAI.sharedInstance().trackUncaughtExceptions = true
googleAnalytics.set(kGAIScreenName, value: screenName)
let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView()
googleAnalytics.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

I put this piece of code in View Controller(s) where ever it was needed.

Hope this help someone. Thanks

Comment: get sample app from https://github.com/phanisai4u/sampleAppsSwift/tree/master/GoogleAnalyticsSampleSwift