# Objective-C Swift bridging header

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header

After successfully using my Xcode created Objective-C bridging header Xcode now returns a Swift Compiler error complaining that the bridging header does not exist.
[image]
I had been able to use the Xcode created bridging header all day yesterday before Xcode generated this error when the project was compiling. I have attempted to resolve the issue with the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146677/swift-bridging-header-import-issue) but have been unable to resolve the issue.
[image]

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try dragging the bridging header file into the bridging header feild, that will auto populate it with the correct path. Do that and let me know if it fixes it

Comment: @Aggressor Unfortunately this hasn't solved it. Along with the error it has introduced a second one, the -Swift.h file is now missing according to Xcode.

Comment: After you dragged in the file can you show me what your bridging header field looks like?

Comment: I also notice you are levels tab, can you show me the combined tab result

Comment: Also show the arrow expanded so I can see the debug and release versions (its possible you only set one)

Comment: @Aggressor  http://imgur.com/VF3V4sU&YdZ4mYO http://imgur.com/VF3V4sU&YdZ4mYO#1

Comment: If you look at the file path in your image just now and the file path of the error in red above, they are not the same. Thats a pretty big hint my friend :)

Comment: @Aggressor http://imgur.com/clQpJfd http://imgur.com/Vy3jMRT Unfortunately the error still persists. I've included some updated screen shots of Xcode

Comment: Try this `$(PROJECT_DIR)/RevisionApp/RevisionApp-Bridging-Header.h`

Comment: And this `$(PROJECT_DIR)/RevisionApp-Bridging-Header.h`

Comment: @Aggressor This is really puzzling me. Nothing seems to be resolving this issue! I don't have a clue what is causing it

Comment: It cant find your bridging header. Somewhere you have the wrong path.

Comment: What's in your bridging header? What is "RevisionApp-Swift.h" that compiler can not find too? Try to comment this line in bridging header.

Answer (score 0):

I moved my project location and Xcode (v 6.4 ) still looked for the bridging header in the old folder location which was weird. The only way I fixed it was by using an absolute path to the bridging header (@Aggressor's solution of just dragging the file into the bridging header field populated the field with an absolute path) . Really hoping that later version of Xcode fix this - it seems like a stupid IDE bug to me...

- Also ensure to check your project Tests target (if you have one) and do the same there