# Swift Compiler Error - failed to import bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, j2objc

I'm trying to integrate [Actor App](https://github.com/actorapp/actor-platform) for iOS. On compiling, I get this error :

[image]

I checked the path and the **`ActorClient-Bridging-Header.h`** is present there.

I have set the proper path to the header file in **Build Settings**

[image]

And this is the folder structure :

[image]

What might be the reason for this compilation error?

**EDIT**
I tried solving the same as mentioned here : [Swift Bridging Header import issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146677/swift-bridging-header-import-issue) and no luck.

Screenshot of the actual path on my disk : 
[image: .h path]

Comment: @JHHoang There was a problem with the actor configuration which they solved in the new release. You need to delete the old actor files and start from scratch. Download the zip from here : https://github.com/actorapp/actor-platform. Go to 'actor apps' folder and do "./installDeps.sh". Once that gets complete, go to 'app-ios' & do 'pod install'. Voila :) You can now build the project.

Comment: see [a quick solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046676/file-not-found-in-bridging-header-when-importing-objective-c-frameworks-into-s/34046677#34046677)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your project's Framework Search Path,which I assume would be empty and add the path of your SDK folder there.
For adding the path correctly, you can just drag and drop your SDK folder here,the correct path from root will be added automatically.
Hope this will help!!

Answer (score 0):

Bridging header file should be placed at root folder.

[image]