# Unable to import iSpeech into my iOS Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, speech, ispeech

As the iSpeechSDK is written for Objective-C, I tried to import it in my existing iOS project using a bridging-header. I've copied all the associated headers and frameworks. However, I'm still unable to call the Objective-C class. See the attached screenshot. Let me know how I can resolve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work by following Renan Kosicki's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24293717/4275096. My header file wasn't created at the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually an error as a result of a circular reference. You should have to import a class in your view controller , and that classes header file was importing the swift header

**In your viewcontrollor.swift :**

```
import iSpeechSDk
import .... // Add your class
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: iSpeechSDK is in Objective-C. I'm unable to import it in this manner. It says "No such module 'iSpeechSDK'".

Comment: In which class you want to import your objejective c class ?

Comment: Yes, I'm importing this into my Swift project via a bridging-header

Comment: What you have to do is goto your view controller in swift you can add this in your swift class.. you don't have to add this in objective c class

Comment: As mentioned, I tried but it doesn't recognise the module 'iSpeechSDK'. I assume I may not have imported it properly using the bridging-header.

Comment: First clarify one thing where you want to use iSpeechSDK ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100232/discussion-between-mayank-patel-and-mechdon).