# failed to import bridging header file in swift

Tags: ios, swift, onedrive

I am getting this error while running [this](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sample-sync-ios) project.

`failed to import bridging header '/Users/OdysseyApps/Desktop/ashraf/onedrive-sample-sync-ios-master/OneAPI Sync/OneAPI Sync-Bridging-Header.h'`

I think the problem is the space in project name OneAPI Sync.
please give me some suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Bridging Header import issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146677/swift-bridging-header-import-issue)

Comment: The space is a likely problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably You have imported some class in bridge file.
That is not a part of your bundle.(or didn't accidentally imported .m file)
Try to find that class and remove that class import statement.