# Error Building for Unity in Native iOS App

Tags: c#, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine, native

Iam beginner in iOS development. 
I would like to get help for Unity in Native iOS App sample. I went through few online course which is outdated also showing some error at the end. I would like to request if anyone could post a video tutorial or sample project to make Unity in Native iOS app .. here is sample link :- https://medium.com/@IronEqual/how-to-embed-a-unity-game-into-an-ios-native-swift-app-772a0b65c82 like so..

[image]

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: @ Rurouni, I tried more than 10 sample projects, it always shows some error like PrecompileSwiftBridgeHeader failed with a nonzero exit code error or Clang. If I clear those again comes up with another.. Its really hard. that y asked for any latest video or sample.

Comment: @Aleesha.... show the screen shot of the error

Comment: @wings, its really hard to find proper solution, only by building the sample u could find..

Comment: Try updating all IDEs to latest versions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146677/swift-bridging-header-import-issue try all these solutions

Answer (score 2):

As per your request I have uploaded a video tutorial for building Unity in Native iOS App with latest version of Xcode-10.1 and unity -2018.2.18f1.

Youtube link- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLkeGz5vCzk

The source code for App Delegate is,

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *unityWindow;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UnityAppController *unityController;
- (void) showUnityWindow;
- (void) hideUnityWindow;


@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate
- (UIWindow *)unityWindow {
    return UnityGetMainWindow();
}
- (void) showUnityWindow {
    [self.unityWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
}
- (void) hideUnityWindow{
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [UIScreen mainScreen]. bounds];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ViewController *mainVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainIdentity"];
    UINavigationController *naVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];
    self.window.rootViewController = naVC;
    self.unityController = [[UnityAppController alloc] init];
    [self.unityController application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions];

    return YES;

}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    [self.unityController applicationWillResignActive:application];
}


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    [self.unityController applicationDidEnterBackground:application];
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

    [self.unityController applicationWillEnterForeground:application];
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    [self.unityController applicationDidBecomeActive:application];
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

    [self.unityController applicationWillTerminate:application];
}


@end
```

And View Controller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isShowUnityWindow;
- (IBAction)showUnityTouched:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *unityViewStart;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.isShowUnityWindow = NO;

}


- (IBAction)showUnityTouched:(id)sender {
    self.isShowUnityWindow = !self.isShowUnityWindow;
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    if (self.isShowUnityWindow) {
       [appDelegate.unityWindow setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 200, 500, 500)];
        [appDelegate.unityWindow ]

        [appDelegate showUnityWindow];

    }
    else {
        [appDelegate hideUnityWindow];
    }
}
@end
```